# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Can't query from User database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an endpoint on my Flask app that will show all user info (I know this is unsafe, its for debugging).

I have created the route with the following code:

```
@main_bp.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def userInfo():
    from .models import User
    q = User.query.all()
    return str(q)
```

This ends up returning `[]`, while I know for a fact that there are users in the database. Further, when selecting a single record, I am able to get the username as follows:

```
def userInfo():
    from .models import User
    q = User.query.first()
    return str(q.username)
```

I am using SQLite3, but plan to move to PostgreSQL soon, so if the problem lies within SQLite, the ideal solution would be to just connect to a PG database instead.

Comment: how do you see that it is returning `[]`?

Comment: @thebjorn In the first code snippet, I directly return the `str()` of the response. There is a likely chance that I am just not accessing the data in the proper way

Comment: Sure, but are you looking at the rendered html? (which would contain `"[<...>]"` where the angle brackets would be swallowed by the html...). What about `str([v.username for v in q])`?

Comment: @thebjorn No, I was looking at the direct response, but I am able to access it with your second command. But this would mean I have to manually map all of the fields I want to display, which I would rather have it dynamically return all fields.

Comment: No, it shows that you have been returned a list of `User` objects, but that those objects don't have a `__str__` or `__repr__` that make them visible from where you're looking at them.

Comment: @thebjorn I understand that. I'm saying how do I get all of the columns "visible"

Comment: Normally you would use a template to either display fields you know, or iterate over all fields to display them. I don't know enough about SQLAlchemy internals to tell you how to do that however...

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a weird error. Try looping through q and adding the names to double check like so:

```
@main_bp.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def userInfo():
    from .models import User
    users = User.query.all()
    result = ''
    for u in users:
        result += str(u.username)

    return result
```

See if you get anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. I have also a "User" in sqlalchemy, and if I copy your code, I only have to change the name of the app, and it works:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def userInfo():
  from .models import User
  q = User.query.all()
  return str(q)
```

If you are sure that you have users in the DB, maybe this code is not executed? Something weird: redundant route?